# JS onClick transform rotate problem horizontal vertical

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, transform

I want to implement

**updown** button work always vertical direction

and

**leftRight** button work always horizon direction. from current image position

But here my probem after rotate first time if i try to rotate from another way at first it move to initial position without rotating from that position.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#choose_nail_reflect_side', function(e) {

        var items = $('#order_nail_img');
        var lengths = items.length;
        var index = 0;
        $("#order_nail_img").addClass('side');
        
   
        console.log($("#order_nail_img").css('transform'));


            if ($("#order_nail_img").css('transform') == 'none') {
              $("#order_nail_img").css({'transform': 'rotateY(-180deg)'});
            }
            else {
                $("#order_nail_img").css({'transform': ''});
            };
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#choose_nail_reflect_updown', function(e) {

        var items = $('#order_nail_img');
        var lengths = items.length;
        var index = 0;
        $("#order_nail_img").addClass('down');
      
            if ($("#order_nail_img").css('transform') == 'none') {
              $("#order_nail_img").css({'transform': 'rotateX(-180deg)'});
            } 
            else {
               $("#order_nail_img").css({'transform': ''});
            };
    });
```

```css
#choose_nail_reflect_side {
   
    margin-top: 56px;
}
#choose_nail_reflect_updown {

}

#order_nail_img {
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img id="order_nail_img" src="https://i.imgur.com/KA2dxD6.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="btn  bgSalmon W150 aCenter" id="choose_nail_reflect_updown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">upDown</a>
</div>

<div class="btn  bgSalmon W150 aCenter" id="choose_nail_reflect_side">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">leftRight</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 cases to handle. Firstly get rid of inline css and let's try doing this with adding/removing class(es).

lets make 3 classes

```
.verticallyInverted {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.horzontallyInverted{
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.allInverted {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

now modify the eventListeners of **updown** and **leftright** buttons as below

```
var imageEl = $('#order_nail_img');    
function handleUpdownClick (){
      if(imageEl.hasClass("horizontallyInverted") {
          imageEl.removeClass("horizontallyInverted");
          imageEl.addClass("allInverted");
      } else if(imageEl.hasClass("verticallyInverted"){
          imageEl.removeClass("verticallyInverted");
      } else if(imageEl.hasClass("allInverted")) {
          imageEl.removeClass("allInverted");
          imageEl.addClass("horizontallyInverted");
      }
}


function handleLeftrightClick (){
          if(imageEl.hasClass("verticallyInverted") {
              imageEl.removeClass("verticallyInverted");
              imageEl.addClass("allInverted");
          } else if(imageEl.hasClass("horizontallyInverted"){
              imageEl.removeClass("horizontallyInverted");
          } else if(imageEl.hasClass("allInverted")) {
              imageEl.removeClass("allInverted");
              imageEl.addClass("verticallyInverted");
          }
}
```

I expect your code supports jQuery.

Comment: thanks your code helped. but there were needed some modification. https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/z30Ldpej/